# Why does ci` jump into the backticks but ci( does not jump into braces?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a textfile like this:

```
this is some test `more test` 
this is some test (more test)
```

If I am at the beginning of the first line and type ci` the cursor will jump into the backticks, replaces the content inside and let's me edit.

However, if I am at the beginning of the second line and I type ci( nothing will happen.

What's the reason for this behavior? Is there a setting that might change it?

Comment: Read `:h motion.txt`.

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19/why-does-ci-and-ci-behave-differently

Comment: Check out [welle/targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the internal behavior of vim 7.4:

- For blocks `()`,`{}`,`[]`,`<>`:

Vim searches backwards and then forwards starting from current position to match the opening and closing character.

- For quotes `""`, `''`, **``** :

Vim spans the whole line, where the cursor is, till it finds the quotes.

Here is the last case where there is no quotechar under the cursor:

```c
/* Search backward for a starting quote. */
    col_start = find_prev_quote(line, col_start, quotechar, curbuf->b_p_qe);
    if (line[col_start] != quotechar)
    {
        /* No quote before the cursor, look after the cursor. */
        col_start = find_next_quote(line, col_start, quotechar, NULL);
        if (col_start < 0)
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* Find close quote character. */
    col_end = find_next_quote(line, col_start + 1, quotechar,curbuf->b_p_qe);
```